# Why does "Building wheel for TA-Lib (setup.py)" take a long time?

Tags: python, ta-lib

I tried installing TA-Lib on an Ubuntu virtual machine.

Everything was done according to the documentation (https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/install.html). The installation stops on

```
Building wheel for TA-Lib (setup.py)
```

after running

```
pip3 install TA-Lib"
```

Tried waiting but it makes no sense. Any idea?

[image: screenshot of logs]

Answer (score 3):

Then try bin:

```
pip3 install ta-lib-bin
```